# Creating a variable number of methods and resources within an API Gateway resource

Tags: terraform

I currently use a Lambda function that uses API Gateway as its trigger, and the methods and endpoints within API Gateway are created manually. I'm trying to move this over to create it automatically with Terraform. I'm pretty new to Terraform though and I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a looping structure since the number of methods and endpoints can be different for each lambda function.

I've read up on templates and interpolation, but because what I need has 2 layers, I can't really piece together what the best solution would be

This is an example of what I may go off of when manually creating the gateway resources. Assume the number of endpoints can vary and the number of methods within each endpoint can also vary.

```
{
  "api_name" : "branches",
  "api_description" : "Branches API",
  "endpoints" : [
    {
      "name" : "branch1",
      "path" : "branch1/Retail/GetData",
     "methods" : [
        {
          "type" : "get",
          "folder" : "branches",
          "handler" : "index.handler",
          "authenticator": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "branch2",
      "path" : "branch2/Retail/GetData",
      "methods" : [
        {
          "type" : "get",
          "folder" : "branches",
          "handler" : "index.get_handler",
          "authenticator": false
        },
        {
          "type" : "post",
          "folder" : "branches",
          "handler" : "index.post_handler",
          "authenticator": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like the end result to produce something like this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "LambdaTrigger" {
  name        = "${var.API_NAME}"
  description = "${var.API_DESCRIPTION}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "Resource1" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.LambdaTrigger.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.LambdaTrigger.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "GetData"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "Method1" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.LambdaTrigger.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource1.id}"
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "Resource2" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.LambdaTrigger.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.LambdaTrigger.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "GetData"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "Method2" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.LambdaTrigger.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource2.id}"
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "Method2" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.LambdaTrigger.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource2.id}"
  http_method   = "POST"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot do loops on loops like you are wanting and modules do not currently support `count`, you can create your Resource/Method groups via a [module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html) and then call the module each time for a resource/module group.

I tweaked your meta data object with a `path_part` field.

```
{
  "api_name" : "branches",
  "api_description" : "Branches API",
  "endpoints" : [
    {
      "name" : "branch1",
      "path" : "branch1/Retail/GetData",
      "path_part": "GetData",  // added for simplicity
     "methods" : [
        {
          "type" : "get",
          "folder" : "branches",
          "handler" : "index.handler",
          "authenticator": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "branch2",
      "path" : "branch2/Retail/GetData",
      "path_part": "GetData",  //added for simplicity
      "methods" : [
        {
          "type" : "get",
          "folder" : "branches",
          "handler" : "index.get_handler",
          "authenticator": false
        },
        {
          "type" : "post",
          "folder" : "branches",
          "handler" : "index.post_handler",
          "authenticator": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a module for making a resource and its methods. It would go in a separate folder to be referenced by your main file. For any terraform project, I tend to have a `modules` folder for all of my modules, so something like `./modules/api_resources`

```
# variables.tf
variable "rest_api_id" {
  type = "string"
}
variable "rest_api_root_resource_id" {
  type = "string"
}
variable "endpoints" {
  type = "list"
}
```

```
# main.tf
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "resource" {
  rest_api_id = "${var.rest_api_id}"
  parent_id   = "${var.rest_api_root_resource_id}"

  path_part   = "${var.endpoints[count.index].path_part}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "method" {
  count = "${length(var.endpoint.methods)}"

  rest_api_id = "${var.rest_api_id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id}"
  http_method   = "${var.endpoint.methods[count.index].type}"
  authorization = "${var.endpoint.methods[count.index].authenticator ? "WHATEVER_AUTH_TYPE_YOU_ARE_USING" : "NONE"}"
}
```

```
#outputs.tf
output "resource_id" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id}"
}
output "resource_path" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.path}"
}
```

Now you can use that module in your main.tf once for each part of `endpoints`.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "lambda_trigger" {
  name        = "${var.api_name}"
  description = "${var.api_description}"
}

module "resource1" {
  source = "./modules/api_resources"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.lambda_trigger.id}"
  rest_api_root_resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.lambda_trigger.root_resource_id}"
  endpoints = "${var.endpoints[0]}"
}


module "resource2" {
  source = "./modules/api_resources"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.lambda_trigger.id}"
  rest_api_root_resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.lambda_trigger.root_resource_id}"
  endpoints = "${var.endpoints[1]}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've taken your structure idea and implemented it. I'm still struggling with one of the "loops" though. If I don't know how many endpoints I will be passed, is there a way to call a variable number of the modules? I'm thinking I may need to programmatically create a different terraform file for each endpoint from my deploy script. Thoughts on that approach?

Comment: You would be able to do the loop over the endpoints if Terraform supported the `count` parameter for modules, but it does not. Instead you will just need to define a separate module for each item in your endpoint. It is not ideal. If you are trying to avoid touching the file each time a new endpoint is added, you could make a script to regenerate `main.tf` from the json describing your API, but how often will you add new endpoints vs. all the other work?